# Selecting a column that doesn't exist - why does this TSQL run and what is it doing?

Tags: t-sql

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    TableA 
WHERE
    TableA.ColumnA NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT ColumnA FROM TableB)
```

- TableA.ColumnA # exists.
- TableB.ColumnA # does not exist.

Why does this even run? What is going on in the subselect?

Comment: what's the table definition of TABLEB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't specify `TableB.ColumnA`, so the database resolved it to the unambiguous `TableA.ColumnA`.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought that could happen since table A isn't in the subqueries WHERE clause. I guess it's a general property of subqueries that they can reference tables in the "super query" (if that's the word)?

Comment: You could have had `... where TableA.ColumnA not in ( select TableA.ColumnB - TableB.Discount from TableB );`. Data from the outer query is available in the inner query and is frequently used to correlate the two, e.g. `... where TableA.ColumnA not in ( select TableB.ColumnFoo from TableB where TableB.Id != TableA.Id );` to avoid rows matching their kissin' cousins in another table. One lesson: Always use explicit two-part names (and friendly aliases) when playing with multiple tables in a query. It makes the intent clearer and will break when something goes missing.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

HABO has it right.

When the engine fails to find ColumnA in TableB, during the subquery, it presumes this is a correlated subquery. This means values from TableA are in scope during the subquery. Since you didn't manually specify in the NOT IN statement TableB.ColumnA, your WHERE clause begins to read like this:

```
SELECT *

FROM TableA

WHERE TableA.ColumnA NOT IN (SELECT TableA.ColumnA FROM TableA)
```

Effectively, it's a trivial query that can't possibly return anything, given the underlying infrastructure.